# Customize wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, customization, banner

How can I remove the current banner and replace with my own div which has enquire form?
    [Website link](http://immediatebankclaims.co.uk)

[image: banner]

[image: Form]

Answer (score 0):

ftp to your serwer go to wp-content/themes/(theme you pick) and change header.php file should be easy.

Comment: What section in header.php do I need to make changes

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is your default banner image:

http://immediatebankclaims.co.uk/wp-content/themes/typal-makewp005/img/default-head-bg.png

You can either change it via theme options(if available in the theme), else write css to the the **"#home-tagline"** id and set the background image of your new banner path. So it can be changed.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I would like to remove banner and have Enquire form on the right side.

Comment: Inside this '<div id="home-tagline"></div>' add your form. And remove the banner by applying this style. #home-tagline:background:none;. Then use your form within the div and do some css stuffs.

Comment: Hi I was trying to find `<div id="home-tagline"></div>` in header.php cannot find, please help me the location.

Comment: Which theme are you using.? Is it your custom theme or theme from web.?